# Decimal to quaternary (base 4) conversion?

Tags: r

Is there a R program that can convert decimal to base 4 (quaternary) number for decimals between 0 and 1? I tried finding online but without any luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows users can use my `expansions` package. To install:

```
devtools::find_rtools()
devtools::install_github('stla/expansions', build_vignettes=TRUE)
```

or from my `drat` repo:

```
devtools::find_rtools()
drat::addRepo("stlarepo")
install.packages("expansions")
```

or download the zip file [here](https://github.com/stlarepo/drat/tree/gh-pages/bin/windows/contrib/3.3) and install it.

You are interested in the `floatExpand01` function (`floatExpand01(x, base=4)`).

### Short overview of the package

#### Decimal integer to integer base:

```
n <- 14
(n_to_base3 <- intAtBase(n, base=3) )
## [1] 2 1 1
sum(n_to_base3*c(1,3,3^2)) == n
## [1] TRUE
```

#### Cantor expansion:

```
# Cartesian product {0,1}x{0,1,2}x{0,1}:
sapply(0:11, function(x) intToAry(x, sizes=c(2,3,2)))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
## [1,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1     0     1
## [2,]    0    0    1    1    2    2    0    0    1     1     2     2
## [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     1     1     1
```

#### Float expansion in integer base, number between 0 and 1:

```
x <- 0.625
( x_to_base2 <- floatExpand01(0.625, base=2) )
## [1] 1 0 1
sum(x_to_base2 / 2^(1:3)) == x
## [1] TRUE
```

#### Float expansion in integer base, positive number:

```
x <- 1.125
( x_to_base2 <- floatExpand(1.125, base=2) )
## $digits
## [1] 1 0 0 1
## 
## $exponent
## [1] 1
sum(x_to_base2$digits / 2^(1:4)) * 2^x_to_base2$exponent == x
## [1] TRUE
```

#### Addition of adic integers:

```
sumadic(c(0,1,1), c(1,0,1), base=2)
## [1] 1 1 0 1
```

#### To know more:

http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/expansions_package.html

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2167741 Have you tried the package? You would be the first one. Did you manage to install it? Your feedback is welcome.

Comment: Yes, I did on the spare windows machine I had and it worked. However, when I tried to compile it on the OS X (I usually work), it failed. It will be great to have this on mac. Now I have to process the data in the windows machine and transfer it.

Comment: @user2167741 Nice. It works only on Windows because it depends on a DLL. Moreover this DLL is created from Haskell and Haskell generate standalone dynamic libraries only for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to get the string length of the decimal number. So for instance if `x = 0.012`, then `str_length(as.character(x)) - 2 = 3`. So we multiply `x` by `10^3` and then we apply the usual algorithm to convert from one base to another base. See [here](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html).

Comment: Sure, but how do we get the representation back to the actual number from its "integer" version? Here we would just get the representation for the number 12 and not 0.012, right?